# Do distinct elements of $S_n$ afford distinct inner automorphisms of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Do distinct elements of $S_n$ afford distinct inner automorphisms of $S_n$?

I believe that this is true but am wondering if there is a way to prove this just by appealing to general facts about automorphisms and/or $S_n$, rather than doing it mechanically.

Comment: Let $s \in S_n$. Then, in cycle notation, $s(a_1a_2...a_m)s^{-1} = (s(a_1)s(a_2)...s(a_m))$.

Comment: @Vik78 Could you elaborate a bit? How exactly does this lead to a proof?

Comment: Well for one thing it may actually enable you to show that $S_n$ is centerless for $n>2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\gamma$ from a group $G$ to its inner automorphism group, which assigns to $g$ the automorphism of conjugation by $g$, has kernel equal to the center $Z(G)$. Thus, if $G$ is centerless, $\gamma$ is 1-1, and distinct elements of $g$ afford distinct inner automorphisms. $S_n$ is centerless if $n>2$.

Comment: Why is the map a homomorphism?

Comment: For all $x$, $\gamma(ab)(x) = (ab)x(ab)^{-1} = abxb^{-1}a^{-1}=(\gamma(a)\circ\gamma(b))(x)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!